# Why does "Krabben" mean shrimp?

Tags: meaning

I was in a pizza place in Bad Herrenalb (in Baden-Württemberg) the other day, and I ordered a pizza that included "Krabben".  I like crab, so I ordered it, only to find that it came covered with shrimp.

My dictionary says that Krabbe means crab, and that Krabben is the plural.  So how did I end up with a pizza full of shrimp instead?

Comment: At the rim of nowhere from the sea you should probably not expect too much of expertise in seafood - at least not on a pizza ;)

Comment: Krabben means crabs. The shelly dudes walking on bottom of sea with big nasty schnap-schnaps at the ends of their arms. That you actually get something else if you order it must be originating from some pizzeria making a language mistake long ago.

Comment: Could you put a picture of the thing you want to eat in the question? I have an inkling that that what you want is normally not available on pizza.

Comment: Anything on this page without "imitation" in front of it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_meat

Comment: And I think you're right that crab meat isn't usually found on pizza, but personally I'm not accustomed to finding sea bugs on pizza either.  We don't eat out much here, I guess.

Comment: @Kyralessa Is "sea bugs" an official term for shrimps somewhere? I can not find it on my dictionaries.

Comment: No, it's not an official term yet, but I'm trying to make it happen.

Comment: I have looked up the prices for e.g. genuine crabs and it is **32 €/kg**, so I take a guess that it is simply much too expensive for normal pizza in Germany. I will write an answer later if it is available at all, but just for curiosity: Where in the world can people actually get genuine crab meat on pizza?

Comment: No idea.  I know of a Mexican restaurant back in St. Louis, Missouri, USA, where one can get crab enchiladas.  If that helps.  (It's real crab; I asked.)

Comment: @Kyralessa So you are complaining about ambiguous terms and don't use well-defined terms yourself? Tststs :D

Comment: Based on the photo of the girl in the orange jacket, it's probably wise to keep your nose away from its claws.

Comment: On a related note, I caution you to resist the urge to order a "Peperoni-Pizza" while in Germany!

Comment: @greenSocksRock Doch, I love spicy food.

Comment: You call shrimp "sea-bugs", but you eat crabs?  How much more bug-like could something be without being an actual bug!

Comment: Nah, see, crabs are more like sea _spiders_.

Comment: Incidentally, English also calls a lot of things crabs that are not crabs, e.g. horseshoe crabs, hermit crabs.  Part of that is there there are a lot of creatures scuttling around down there that look like crabs but are not, a phenomenon called [carcinisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcinisation).

Comment: @ThorstenS.: Man darf nicht billige Ersatzstoffe unter dem Namen teurer Originale, mit der Begründung, die teuren seien zu teuer, verkaufen. Das wäre Betrug. Die Bezeichnung "Krabbe" muss schon Usus sein.

Comment: @Takkat while right at the shore, "Krabben" are "Granat" (literally: garnet).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ok, the short guide to crustaceans seafood in Germany.

Unfortunately the usage of *Krabben* (crab/shrimp), *Krebs* (crab), *Garnelen* (shrimp) and so in German reduce biologists to tears. It is **ambigous** and often wrong from the view of biology.

Also the english equivalents of crab, crayfish, shrimps or lobster are not exactly 1:1 translateable because of different meanings. In German, e.g. *Krebs* is both used for zodiac sign, the illness and a specific kind of crustaceans.

#### Nordsee-Garnele (even officially Nordsee-Krabbe), Porren, Granat,  Krevetten (*Crangon crangon*).

This is what you get normally if you order "Krabben" or "Garnelen" on a pizza. [It is widely used for literally everything as you can see in the German wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crangon_crangon)).
[image]
*Lou Stejskal, CC BY-SA 2.0 2016-08-17*

[image]
*Public Domain, 2018-03-18*

#### Gambas, Riesengarnele (mostly Litopenaeus vannamei)

Germans use the Spanish word "Gambas" normally to describe big shrimps aka king prawns. It is very unspecified, only length counts, they should be at least 6cm long.

Types:

- **White-Tiger Garnele (*Litopenaeus vannamei*)**, in English whiteleg shrimp or king prawn.
  [image]
  *Xufanc, CC BY-SA 3.0, 2011-11-30*
- **Eismeer-Garnele, Grönlandkrabbe (*Pandalus borealis*)**, in English northern prawn.
  [image]
  *Alaska Fischeries, Public Domain, 2011-09-14*
- **Argentinische Rotgarnele (*Pleoticus muelleri*, auch *Langostinos Patagonicos*)**, in English argentine red shrimp.
  [image]
  *Assianir, CC BY-SA 4.0, 2015-06-02*

#### Black-Tiger Garnele, Black-Tiger Shrimp (*Penaeus monodon*)

An alternative to the Nordsee-Garnele it is marketed as Black-Tiger Garnele/Shrimp (yes, the English is unchanged in Germany), it is also offered on pizza. [In English giant tiger prawn or Asian-tiger shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penaeus_monodon).
[image]
*GFDL, 2008-11-10*

#### Scampi, Kaisergranat, Hummerkrabbe (*Nephrops norvegicus*)

They are both known as "Scampi" or "Kaisergranat" (rare) in Germany.
Allegedly extremely delicious, they are shrimps which are found in luxury restaurants. [There have been several incidences where restaurants in Hamburg have served cheaper shrimps despite being explicitly ordered Scampi](https://www.ndr.de/ratgeber/verbraucher/Restaurants-Scampi-Vapiano-Gosch,scampi152.html). [In English they are known as Scampi or Norway Lobster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scampi)
[image]
*Public domain, 2010-06-07*

#### Taschenkrebs, Knieper (*Cancer pagurus*)

Despite being called a *Krebs*, it is actually a crab. This is the typical real crab fished in the North Sea, almost exclusively used for this purpose; the people on Heligoland call them "Knieper" (Pincher). It's very delicious and in [Heligoland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heligoland) it is in fact used for pizza, the so-called "Knieper pizza" In English it is the [brown crab.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer_pagurus)
[image]
*Hans Hillewaert, CC BY-SA 4.0, 2006-03-06*

#### Krebs, Flusskrebs (river crayfish), Edelkrebs (*Astacus astacus*)

This is what Germans know as archetypical *Krebs* (crab). It you want *Krebs*, this is normally what you get (Because this crab is getting rare, another Astacus species, the *Galizischer Sumpfkrebs* (Astacus leptodactylus) from Eastern Europe is quite often used).

[image]
*Dragon187, CC BY-SA 3.0, 2011-07-01*

#### Hummer, Europäischer Hummer (*Homarus gammarus*)

Like the *Krebs*, this is the archetype of a German *Hummer* (lobster). They are caught near Heligoland, but served everywhere in Germany. [In English common lobster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homarus_gammarus)

[image]
*Bart Braun, Public Domain, 2017-10-22*

#### Königskrabbe (king's crab), Kamtschatkakrabbe, Monsterkrabbe(*Paralithodes camtschaticus*)

Sure it is possible in German to get it wrong the other way round: The *Königskrabbe* is in reality a *Krebs*. While not native in vicinity of Germany (it is bred in the Barents Sea in northern Scandinavia), it is still widely used in restaurants here. [In English it is the red king crab.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_king_crab)
[image]
*National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, Public Domain*

#### Languste, Europäische/Gewöhnliche Languste (*Palinurus elephas*)

The archetypical *Languste* for Germans, it is mostly caught in the Mediterranean Sea. In English [spiny lobster or red lobster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palinurus_elephas).
[image]
*Georges Jansoone, CC BY-SA 3.0, 2009-05-09*

Comment: Interesting! It surprises me, since very little of this confusion exists in Dutch. Shrimps are _garnalen_, crabs are _krab_. No one would ever use one to mean the other.

Comment: @Confusion I disagree. The Dutch word for the Cancer zodiac sign is, wait for it, *kreeft*, 'lobster'.

Comment: Not sure I'm representative for people from, say, southern Niedersachsen, but if you asked me to draw a »Krebs«, I'd definitely draw the Taschenkrebs/Knieper. And »Krabben« are the small North Sea shrimp that the OP complained about.

Answer (score 32):

*Krabbe* can mean

> prawn
>   crab
>   shrimp

according to *my* dictionary, so all is well.

To a German, *Krabben* is equivalent to *Nordsee-Krabben*, which means shrimp. I have never seen any pizza come with *crab* (= Krebs) on it, actually.

Usually, what might be on it are either shrimp (Nordsee-Krabben, which you called sea bugs) or prawns - the latter, however, would be called *Garnelen* then.

As to your question **why** - the only valid answer is "because that's how it is".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82036/discussion-on-answer-by-thorsten-dittmar-why-does-krabben-mean-shrimp).

Comment: "Krebs" und "Krabbe" scheinen von "krabbeln" zu stammen. Es ist denkbar, dass die Namen schon immer regional unterschiedlich verwendet wurden und die offizielle Enigung, was Krebse und was Krabben seien erst später getroffen wurde

Comment: Krabben are Krebse, see Strandkrabbe. Krabbe as to refer to "Nordseegarnelen" is only used in cuisine language.

Answer (score 2):

Biologically, **Krebs** means *any* crustacean (crabs, shirmp, prawns, lobsters etc.).

In common language usage, a **Krebs** is a *crab*. **Krabbe** is another word used for crabs as well.

Now, in cuisine, **Krabbe** also refers to *shrimp*, which are actually named **Garnelen**